# Apply foreground and fontsize from one page to another

Tags: c#, wpf, events, radio-button

- I've made many pages  in C# WPF and display them in the MainWindow's frame and also that allows the user to move back and forward between the pages ..
- There is a page as a setting page, which allows the user to pick the font color and size using radiobuttons.
- I want to apply the settings the user picked to another page. 
  I've tried many ways and I failed.
- Is it possible to pass the style of the font from the settings page to the other page ?

Also I'm a beginner

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible. Since you are a beginner, i suggest you spend some time with WPF tutorial(s) (including data binding...).

Comment: @elgonzo Thank you for replying.. can you advise me to a good tutorial that can help knowing how to pass the style ?

Answer (score 0):

Three ways to do that using styles 
1.Layout Level 
2.Window level 
3.Application Level
here is the beginner level tutorial [WPF Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/)